# Linq group by element and a sub element

Tags: c#, linq

Structure is basically like this:

**Master:**

```
  Id 
  DocNo
  Laws[]
```

**Laws** is as follows:

```
LawNo
Id
```

I want to group by **DocNo** and **LawNo**.

The expected dictionary keys are:

```
{DocNo, LawNo}
```

And the expected value is

```
Master
```

I tried this but keys are not like the expected

```
master.GroupBy(x => new {x.DocNo, _LawNo = x.Laws.Select(y => y.LawNo).Distinct()});
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample and expect result?

Comment: Is this EF Core (or any other ORM) query?

Comment: @GuruStron It's EF Core

Comment: Then I recommend to set up relation from `Laws` to `Master` for possibly cleaner query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use `SelectMany` before using `GroupBy`, `SelectMany` let `LawNo` flatten as `DocNo`

```
master.SelectMany(x=>x.Laws,(x,y)=>new{x.DocNo,y.LawNo})
      .GroupBy(x=> new {x.DocNo,x.LawNo});
```

Comment: Should not it be `.SelectMany(x=>x.Laws,(x,y)=>new{x, y})` ?

Comment: Yes you understand correctly! Works well. I changed a little bit thanks to @GuruStron.

`var groupedMaster = master.SelectMany(x => x.Laws, (x, y) => new { x, y })
            .GroupBy(z => new { z.x.DocNo, z.y.LawNo });`
Hard to understand but thats the best solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

what I understood from
this

```
 master
    .SelectMany(m => 
        m.Laws.Select(l => (Master : m, Law : l))
    .GroupBy(tuple => new { LawNo: tuple.Law.LawNo, DockNo: tuple.Master.DocNo})
```

Result should be groups of masters.